# Bash dirs, files & files content renaming

Tags: bash, unix, automation, rename

I am trying to change a very simple word ("discussion") by another ("item") in a PHP script with files and a lot of subfolders.

I would like to change this word:
1- in all the files content
2- in the files names
3- in the directories names

A simple loop and some regexp could take care of 2 & 3, but how could I do 1 with bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use sed.

```
sed -i 's/discussion/item/g' <filename>
```